# Dynamic values in a nested rails form not updating

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm building restaurant management app and I have an option to add certain dishes to an order. Dishes are picked from a dropdown list and I want a value of a text field to be updated based upon the chosen dish. [Just like in that gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHQwZ.gif).

As you can see in the gif, the value only gets updated when I choose the first field, not the ones that I add dynamically with cocoon gem. My form haml looks as follows:

```
= simple_form_for @order do |f|
  .meals
    = f.simple_fields_for :meals, @order.meals.build do |meals|
      = render 'meal_fields', f: meals
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add meal', f, :meals
    = f.submit
```

and in `meal_fields.haml` partial

```
.nested-fields
    = f.select(:name, options_for_select(@dishes.map{ |dish| [dish.name, 
{'data-description' => dish.price}]}), {include_blank: true}, {class: 'meal-
name'})
    = f.select :quantity, options_for_select((1..10))
    = f.text_field(:price, disabled: true)
    = link_to_remove_association "X", f
```

My jQuery code for that looks like that:

```
$(".meal-name").change(function(){
    var chosen = $(this).find(":selected");
    var price = chosen.data("description");
    $(this).siblings("input").val(price);
})
```

For me it looks like it should also apply to the updated fields. Is it a bug or a feature? How can I make this code apply to fields I add later as well?

Comment: Try inspecting the class names after clicking the Add meal button. Seems like the class names changed and could be the reason for the problem.

Comment: @Pavan Thanks for the feedback but I've tried it already. I'm trying to figure out the solution according to Unixmonkey answer.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.change` function gets attached to nodes as soon as that code is parsed. New nodes that match the query selector won't have the `.change` event added to them.

Instead, you can watch a parent object for changes, and have it attach events like this:

```
$('#order-form').on('change', '.meal-name', function() {
  console.log('a .meal-time changed');
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's very helpful. It's watching the changes constantly now. However, it doesn't reassign the price when I add the select tags and as a result, the price stays the same. [See the gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/pxrhaIeobTv0c/giphy.gif)